# ORACLE SQL: problem when transforming a NUMBER starting with zero to XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, number-formatting

I have a Stored Procedure in Oracle that generates an XML from some SQL data. I find that for those fields of type NUMBER, if they start with 0, in the output XML, that 0 is not shown, and only the decimals are shown. Example: if the value is 0.82, it is displayed as:

```
<amount>.82</amount>
```

I have already seen that this would be solved by doing a to_Char (0.82, '9990.00') but I would like to know if there is some more general way that I can use within the PL, to be able to transform all the fields of this type when generating the XML (not to having to go one by one because there are many fields to review), and I would like something more generic, so that if a new field is added tomorrow, you will not have to touch the PL to perform the conversion. Is there any option with XMLType? I am using sys_xmlgen to generate it.

For what it's helpful, the output xml is validated against an xsd in which all numeric fields are of a new defined type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="_tipo_num2dec">
<xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
    <xs:pattern value="-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?">
    </xs:pattern>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: number values are always shown without leading zeros. As you said, you need to use `to_char`. Can you show the code of the PL ?

Comment: finally, i'll do by using to_char because the fields of the xml are setting from an Oracle's TYPE object. Those fields were NUMBER(15,2). So i need to transform previously by using TO_CHAR on the stored procedure, before of setting on the object TYPE. Thank yo so much!!